# When the spreadsheet is refreshed or closed the menu item disappears

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will makes a menu item in Google Sheets to send an email when pressed. The menu item will appear when I press run on script editor but then when the Google Sheet is refreshed or closed the menu item disappears.

The code I have was originally working but for some reason no longer works.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1j2Q58oxxcTS-QYmdvaEiNWgyRagqF17rv8o3tYWB1TQ");
  var menu = [{name: "Submit", functionName:"myFunction"}];
   ss.addMenu("Submit Booking", menu)

}

function myFunction() {

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1j2Q58oxxcTS-QYmdvaEiNWgyRagqF17rv8o3tYWB1TQ");
  var email = "removed for privacy reasons";
   var subject = "New Buffel Park Travel Bookings";
  var link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2Q58oxxcTS-QYmdvaEiNWgyRagqF17rv8o3tYWB1TQ/edit#gid=1832370497";
  var message = "New bookings have been submitted for Buffel Park site staff.";
  var html_message = "<p>New bookings have been submitted for Buffel park site staff."+
                     "<p>"+
                     "<p>Booking details can be found <a href=\""+link+"\">here.</a>"+
                     "<p>"+
                     "<p>A PDF copy of the sheet at time of submission is also attached to this email.";

  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Buffel Park Travel Booking.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {htmlBody: html_message,attachments:[attach]});

   var cc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sub = "New bookings have been submitted for Buffel Park site staff.";

  var html = "<p>New bookings have been submitted for Buffel park site staff."+
                     "<p>"+
                    "<p>A PDF copy of the sheet at time of submission is also attached to this email.";
    MailApp.sendEmail (cc, sub, message, {htmlBody: html,attachments:[attach]});
}
```

I just need the button to stay where it is so it sends an email prompt for the request

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com).

Comment: Sorry about that, can you assist at all?

Comment: The script creates a custom menu with menu items, not a custom function / button.

Comment: Is your script an standalone project or a bounded project? Have look for errors that https://script.google.com/home/executions?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior for it to disappear, however it should re-appear pretty quickly once the script has had a little bit of time to run when you open the spreadsheet.

Your issue looks like it's because you're opening the spreadsheet by ID, I tested this myself and opening by ID doesn't seem to work whereas using getActiveSpreadsheet() does:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menu = [{name: "Submit", functionName:"myFunction"}];
  ss.addMenu("Submit Booking", menu);    
}
```